# how do I install mingw64 on kali linux 2.0?

Tags: linux, debian, tar, wine

I have downloaded several packages from these web sites:

https://packages.debian.org/stable/wine-development

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/?source=typ_redirect

Apparently, I have to have Wine installed on Kali Linux too. However, I can't even get that done properly.

```
root@blackJesus:~/Downloads# apt-get install mingw-w64
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mingw-w64
```

I tried unpacking and unzipping several packages and it still won't help. This is the only one that unpacked correctly, and I don't see what it does for me. Maybe I'm wrong and need to try something else, but what do I do from here if this is the solution:

```
root@blackJesus:~/Downloads# tar -xzvf gcc-mingw-w64_8.tar.gz
gcc-mingw-w64-8/
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.source
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.c.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gobjc++-mingw-w64-i686.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/watch
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/g++-mingw-w64-x86-64.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gobjc-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gfortran-mingw-w64-i686.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.ada.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gnat-mingw-w64-i686.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/changelog
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw32.links
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/compat
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gobjc-mingw-w64-i686.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.fortran.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/rules.variant
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.template
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/g++-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/copyright
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.bootstrap
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64-bootstrap.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/g++-mingw-w64-i686.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw32.lintian-overrides    
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.c++.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/README.source
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/patches/
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/patches/disable-multilib.patch
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/patches/mingw-include.patch
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/patches/spelling-fixes-code.patch
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/patches/cpp-intrinsics.patch
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gfortran-mingw-w64-x86-64.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gnat-mingw-w64-x86-64.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gobjc++-mingw-w64-x86-64.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64-i686.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/bootstrap
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64-x86-64.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/rules.bootstrap
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/g++-mingw-w64-i686.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gfortran-mingw-w64-i686.install
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/rules.full
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64.postinst
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/source/
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/source/format
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/source/lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw32.postinst
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.gcc-mingw32
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.base
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.obj-c++.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/rules
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/control.objc.sed
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gnat-mingw-w64-i686.lintian-overrides
gcc-mingw-w64-8/debian/gcc-mingw-w64-i686.install
```

I'm trying to install mingw64 on kali linux. Help?

--update: I've made some progress but still have trouble getting wine installed--

```
root@blackJesus:~/Desktop/MinGW# wine mingw-get-setup.exe 
wine: Bad EXE format for Z:\root\Desktop\MinGW\mingw-get-setup.exe.
```

Comment: why do you need mingw on linux?

Comment: you need to cross-compile mingw64 on Linux. Possible duplicate: [How to cross-compile with MinGW on Linux for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28155308/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify. Wine is a tool that allows you to install and run (many, not all) programs that were designed and compiled for windows. Wine will emulate an Windows environment and allow to run these programs.

What you have to do is install [Wine](https://wiki.debian.org/RunningWindowsPrograms). Search for it with `apt-get` and install. When this is done. Go to the MinGW page download and install the installation executable through Wine (normally just by double clicking the exe).

If the installation was successfull the compiler you want to use to compile programs for Windows should be located at `/root/.wine/drive_c/MinGW/bin`.

Comment: that got Wine installed but when I right click on the file, Wine or windows loader doesn't show up. How do I use Wine then?

Comment: it installed wine but I can't use wine for anything, it only gives me two parameters when I run it. It won't let me open a program in wine.

Comment: I updated the above.

Comment: I also still can't install mingw